# Submitting data in the review mode

Tags: toloka

I have recently tried submitting data in the review mode and faced a number of unexpected issues. Has anybody tried submitting data when in the review mode? If yes, could you, please, share with me some example code, as I'm really stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Review mode is read-only, you cannot run scripts in it or do any other operations with the data received from the task performer.